# Help me get Sierra boradbank modem working (ms8533). I've tried everything I know

Tags: linux-mint

I've gone through every post I can find via google to get my Sierra wireless internal modem working.

**lsusb gives me this:**

```
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 1199:9013 Sierra Wireless, Inc.
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 214b:7000  
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 214b:7000  
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 174c:1153 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM2115 SATA 6Gb/s bridge
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:217f Broadcom Corp. BCM2045B (BDC-2.1)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

It's the **Bus 002 Device 005: ID 1199:9013 Sierra Wireless, Inc.** device.

When I try to use the modem manager gui it lists the device, but tells me I need to enable it. I've gone through the BIOS and everything is enabled there. I've successfully passed a pin code to the device, but that doesn't seem to make a difference. I have a connection configured in NM, but again, the thing is just dead. I can't enable it, make a connection, or anything. It is detected though.

I've placed the mbn firmware files in /lib/firware/gobi and rebooted:

- amss.mbn
- apps.mbn
- UQCN.mbn

I'm really green with this because it's the first time I've tried to set it up.

I'm using Mint 20.1. It's a Sierra MC8355.

**mmcli -m -0 gives this:**

```
-------------------------
  General |         dbus path: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0
  -------------------------
  System  |         device: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4
          |         drivers: qmi_wwan, qcserial
          |         plugin: Sierra
          |         primary port: cdc-wdm1
          |         ports: ttyUSB0 (qcdm), ttyUSB1 (at), wwp0s29u1u4 (net), 
          |                 cdc-wdm1 (qmi)
  -------------------------
  Status  | signal quality: 0% (cached)
  -------------------------
  Modes   |      supported: allowed: any; preferred: none
          |        current: allowed: any; preferred: none
```

**nmcli dev status gives this:**

```
DEVICE             TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION         
enp0s25            ethernet  connected     Wired connection 1 
proton0            tun       connected     proton0            
CC:3B:27:62:16:DA  bt        disconnected  --                 
wlp3s0             wifi      disconnected  --                 
cdc-wdm1           modem     unavailable   --                 
vmnet1             ethernet  unmanaged     --                 
vmnet8             ethernet  unmanaged     --                 
lo                 loopback  unmanaged     -
```

**nmcli> print gives this:**

```
===============================================================================
                      Connection profile details (Magti)
===============================================================================
connection.id:                          Magti
connection.uuid:                        cefda2c9-b170-4ffc-9517-d9cff8db8d25
connection.stable-id:                   --
connection.type:                        gsm
connection.interface-name:              --
connection.autoconnect:                 yes
connection.autoconnect-priority:        0
connection.autoconnect-retries:         -1 (default)
connection.auth-retries:                -1
connection.timestamp:                   0
connection.read-only:                   no
connection.permissions:                 --
connection.zone:                        --
connection.master:                      --
connection.slave-type:                  --
connection.autoconnect-slaves:          -1 (default)
connection.secondaries:                 --
connection.gateway-ping-timeout:        0
connection.metered:                     unknown
connection.lldp:                        default
connection.mdns:                        -1 (default)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ipv4.method:                            auto
ipv4.dns:                               --
ipv4.dns-search:                        --
ipv4.dns-options:                       ""
ipv4.dns-priority:                      0
ipv4.addresses:                         --
ipv4.gateway:                           --
ipv4.routes:                            --
ipv4.route-metric:                      -1
ipv4.route-table:                       0 (unspec)
ipv4.ignore-auto-routes:                no
ipv4.ignore-auto-dns:                   no
ipv4.dhcp-client-id:                    --
ipv4.dhcp-timeout:                      0 (default)
ipv4.dhcp-send-hostname:                yes
ipv4.dhcp-hostname:                     --
ipv4.dhcp-fqdn:                         --
ipv4.never-default:                     no
ipv4.may-fail:                          yes
ipv4.dad-timeout:                       -1 (default)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ipv6.method:                            auto
ipv6.dns:                               --
ipv6.dns-search:                        --
ipv6.dns-options:                       ""
ipv6.dns-priority:                      0
ipv6.addresses:                         --
ipv6.gateway:                           --
ipv6.routes:                            --
ipv6.route-metric:                      -1
ipv6.route-table:                       0 (unspec)
ipv6.ignore-auto-routes:                no
ipv6.ignore-auto-dns:                   no
ipv6.never-default:                     no
ipv6.may-fail:                          yes
ipv6.ip6-privacy:                       -1 (unknown)
ipv6.addr-gen-mode:                     stable-privacy
ipv6.dhcp-send-hostname:                yes
ipv6.dhcp-hostname:                     --
ipv6.token:                             --
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
gsm.number:                             *99#
gsm.username:                           --
gsm.password:                           <hidden>
gsm.password-flags:                     0 (none)
gsm.apn:                                --
gsm.network-id:                         --
gsm.pin:                                <hidden>
gsm.pin-flags:                          0 (none)
gsm.home-only:                          no
gsm.device-id:                          --
gsm.sim-id:                             --
gsm.sim-operator-id:                    --
gsm.mtu:                                auto
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
proxy.method:                           none
proxy.browser-only:                     no
proxy.pac-url:                          --
proxy.pac-script:                       --
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

*If someone could help me with this, I would be very grateful.*

Comment: Just as a note re your title, if you've "_tried everything_" then there's nothing else anyone can offer you, and it closes down your question somewhat. I'd suggest that you remove that part of your question title and leave the question text still showing what you have tried. Good luck...

Comment: If you tried everything, no need to ask then.

Comment: You've got to be kidding me. It's a common expression in the English language. Do you guys swap Noddy Cards in your spare time?